# can't upload files in apache2 server with PHP, but can upload files on the default PHP server

Tags: php

I want to ask, why when I run the file to upload images to the server with php on the apache2 server it doesn't run, but when I try to run it with the default PHP server (php -S localhost:8888) it runs fine, and can be uploaded?

Here I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS OS, and Apache2 Server, Mysql, and PHP 7.4.3

Here's the code

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="gambar" id="gambar">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["gambar"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["gambar"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["gambar"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gambar"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["gambar"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
```

when I open it using the apache2 server, and I try to upload a file, a message like the following appears:

"File is an image - image/png.Sorry, your file was not uploaded."

but when I use the default php server, the following success message appears

"File is an image - image/png.The file 1.png has been uploaded."
and the file was successfully uploaded to the directory.

I have tried looking for references about the error, but can't find anything. Then I opened the error log and found the following error

```
[Sun May 01 11:01:11.036227 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 871] [client ::1:54174] PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var /www/html/latihan/upload.php on line 4>
[Sun May 01 11:01:11.036548 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 871] [client ::1:54174] PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php5JG7e2' to 'uploads/1. png' in /var/www/html/latihan/upload.php on line 43, >
[Sun May 01 11:16:33.000929 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 871] [client ::1:54186] PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/2.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var /www/html/latihan/upload.php on line >
[Sun May 01 11:16:33.000966 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 871] [client ::1:54186] PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php6xNhH4' to 'uploads/2. jpeg' in /var/www/html/latihan/upload.php on line 43,>
```

please, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: check whether (1) the upload folder is write-permitted and (2) the path is correct

Comment: @KenLee Yes, sir, my problem has been solved, it turns out that the folder permissions are restricted so the move_uploaded_file() function doesn't work